# How to find the keys of an element which we rendered dynamically with map in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I am trying to get the key of an element which i rendered by using map function giving a unique key.
Anybody who know can comment the answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
<div>
{items.map((item, index) => <div key={index} onClick={(e) => yourFunction(key)}>something</div>)}
</div>
```

On click function with `key`.

```
function yourFunction(key) {
    const selectedItem = data[key];
    // logic here.
}
```

Comment: thats for mapping,I want that key when i click the div which i rendered through map with the key provided.

Comment: I added onClick usage with `key`. Please let me know. But I recommend that you need to write more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

it can be easily done,we just have to pass the key in the function which we want to call on that event.

```
{item && item.map((i)=> (<h1 key={i.key} onClick={(i)=>findKey(i.key)}>Item {i.value}</h1>))
```

And our fuction should be like:

```
function findKey(key){
    console.log(key)
}
```